# Why stirring an over-fermented sourdough starter caused it to rise a second time to about double the original size?

Tags: bread, sourdough, sourdough-starter

After feeding my sourdough starter, I let it rise to about 2.5x the original height. It eventually collapsed. 24 hours later, after it was well over fermented, I stirred the starter with a spoon. It then suddenly grew back to 2x in about 1 to 2 hours, without adding any water or flour. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

You actually kneaded the dough. This puts some of the flour and water into contact with yeast that didn't have access to food cause it already ate all its sources within their grasp. Feeding these yeast cells this way caused the second rise, a common method in bread making.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP is describing.  He fed his starter.  After it consumed the "food", he stirred without adding more flour.  I assume that means it was well mixed to begin with.  @Pat should clarify this point.

Comment: So if I understand, even after mixing the starer well, there will still be portion of flour that haven't been consumed by the yeast in the starter even hours later and by agitating it again, it allows the yeast to get in contact with unconsumed flour that was already there but for some reason was inaccessible to the yeast in the first rise?

Comment: @Pat Yes.......